# Как в PHP работает подстановка переменной в строку?

Tags: php, ascii

Почему скрипт

```
<?php 
    $x="2";
    $y="3";
    $z="\x$x$y";
    echo $z;
?>
```

Выводит строку `\x23`, а не символ `#`? Как в `PHP` работает подстановка переменной в строку?

Comment: Объясните, почему вы решили, что должен выводиться символ `#`?

Comment: я думал, что интерпретатор СНАЧАЛА подставит значение переменных $x и $y, а ПОТОМ начнет читать заново полученную строку, увидит \x23 и подумает "да это же символ #". и влепит его туда

Comment: Я не знаю откуда у вас такая информация, но уверяю - интерпретатор не настолько ... э ... своеобразен :) А как на самом работает интерполяция строк (не только в PHP, но и во многих языках в принципе) можно найти на каждом углу, прото вбив поисковый запрос "интерполяция строк". И не надо ничего придумывать, всё чётко расписано.

Comment: ничего четко не расписано. если ввести "интерполяция переменных в php", то выдаст десятки ОБЗОРНЫХ одинаковых статей, которые скопированы из какого-то одного источника

Comment: [Тык мышкой](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Answer (score 2):

> я думал, что интерпретатор СНАЧАЛА подставит значение переменных $x и $y, а ПОТОМ начнет читать заново полученную строку, увидит \x23 и подумает "да это же символ #". и влепит его туда

Нет, интерполяция всегда делается в один проход. Хотя бы из соображений элементарной логики: многопроходная интерполяция может (и будет) приводить к непредсказуемым результатам, предвидеть которые в большинстве случаев просто невозможно. Не говоря уж о том, что это будет замедлять работу интерпретатора, а главное - просто не нужно.

Так что в самом простом случае делается банальная строковая подстановка и 
ничего больше. Подробности описаны в руководстве по PHP, раздел ["Обработка переменных"](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

В более сложных случаях используются наборы правил, которые описаны в разделе "Сложный (фигурный) синтаксис" там же.